# Clicking on an item in recyclerview: Error reading from input stream

Tags: android

I'm pretty new to Android development and I've been following some tutorial and have managed to get a recycler view populated with data from a url that returns a json object.

Recently, I have tried to add a click listener to the items in the recycler view but whenever I click on the items the app stops working and I get the following error

`W/ErrorProcessor: onFatalError, processing error from engine(4)
com.google.android.aps.gsa.shared.speech.a.g: Error reading from input stream`

**This is my interface:**

```
public interface ItemClickListener {

    public void onClick(View view, int position, boolean isLongClick);
}
```

**The code for my Adapter class which uses my user class but that's just gets/sets:**

```
public class UserAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UserAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    Context context;

    private List<User> mDataset;

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener {

        public TextView mUserId;
        public TextView mUsername;

        private ItemClickListener itemClickListener;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);

            mUserId = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.user_id);
            mUsername = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.username);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            itemView.setOnLongClickListener(this);
        }

        public void setItemClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
            this.itemClickListener = itemClickListener;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            itemClickListener.onClick(v, getAdapterPosition(), false);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            itemClickListener.onClick(v, getAdapterPosition(), true);
            return true;
        }
    }

    public UserAdapter(List<User> myDataset) {
        mDataset = myDataset;
    }

    @Override
    public UserAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_user, parent, false);

        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.mUserId.setText(mDataset.get(position).getUserId());
        holder.mUsername.setText(mDataset.get(position).getUsername());

        holder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, int position, boolean isLongClick) {
                if (isLongClick) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Long Click: " + mDataset.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "" + mDataset.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.size();
    }
}
```

**This is my Activity which handles the volley call and the recycler view** *(I use a separate class for parsing the output and making it into json object I can work with, if necessary I can post the code for that too but I don't see its relevance):*

```
public class UserActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    List<User> mDataset;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    private DividerItemDecoration mDividerItemDecoration;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user);

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvUsers);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        mDividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(mRecyclerView.getContext(), mLayoutManager.getOrientation());
        mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(mDividerItemDecoration);

        sendRequest();
    }

    private void sendRequest() {
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest("http://myurl.com/api/users",
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        ParseCallJSON pj = new ParseCallJSON(response);
                        pj.parsecallJSON();
                        mDataset = pj.getCalls();

                        mAdapter = new CallAdapter(mDataset);
                        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(UserActivity.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
}
```

Comment: You trying to show "User" object as a string in Toast.
What do you want to show on click?

Comment: you have not show your module class so i assume i could be mDataSet.get(position).getName() inside the toast

Comment: @AmeerHamza I tried replacing it with `mDataset.get(position).getUserId()` but it now gives me an error of `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference`

Comment: on same line?it show up

Comment: @AmeerHamza yes, on the line with the Toast.

Comment: @Alex I would like to just show a Toast with the user id.

Comment: ok replace this with Toast.makeText(context, with Toast.makeText(view.getcontext,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
public UserAdapter(List<User> myDataset) {
        mDataset = myDataset;
    }
```

To:

```
public UserAdapter(List<User> myDataset, Context context) {
        mDataset = myDataset;
        this.context=context;
    }
```

Then replace:

```
mAdapter = new CallAdapter(mDataset);
```

to:

```
mAdapter = new CallAdapter(mDataset,UserActivity.this);
```

and on click call:

```
Toast.makeText(context, "Long Click: " + mDataset.get(position).getUserId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```